# Dashed line indicator for matching bracket pair in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, user-experience

Is there a way to make the colored vertical lines indicating bracket pair ranges be drawn with dashed lines, instead of the default, solid style?

I'd like to get something like this:

[image: Visual Studio sample]

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123981 not sure why it's closed and locked. you could consider raising it again. If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket!

Comment: @starball Thank you for letting me know about that closed feature request. I've made a new one: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197066